# Query Multiple Rows Based on Combination of Columns and Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table that shows details for tickets entered.

[image]

I am trying to query this table based on the following

1)  Tickets that have the same Description AND Notes AND appear 2X in an hour.

OR

2)  Tickets that have the same Description AND Notes AND appear 3X or more.

Therefore, the resulting table should be the following.

[image]

I tried using HAVING but couldn't figure out how to include both of the
Description and Notes criteria. I tried to use LAG to see if the previous
record is entered within an hour but that didn't work.

How can I query this?  I appreciate any advice on this.

[Here's](https://rextester.com/HOSBMB78061) the query to create this table.

Comment: Should I rephrase the title to attract more views?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, maybe you have to change any column name. This select should group by date hh:mm and take all entries with 2 or more ocurrences in the same hour.

```
select Description, 
       Notes, 
       convert(varchar(10),Entered,120) + ' '+ convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour,Entered)), 
       count(*)
from WorkEntries
group by Description, 
      Notes, 
      convert(varchar(10),Entered,120) + ' '+ convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour,Entered))
having count(*) > 1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any error reported when executing select? Select is quite simple. It groups by Description, Note and YYYY-MM-DD HH and shows only those who appears at least 2 or more times.

Comment: I've tested the select and it works properly. Perhaps is related to your DBMS version. What's the problem? Why do you say that it doesn't work?